# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText' (Python)

Tags: python, gettext

I learning to code a webscraping in python to extract data of a web page.

I found this code in the internet, but it appears this error:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'`

This is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys

if len(sys.argv)>=2:
    URL=sys.argv[1]

    # url text
    #URL = "https://www.mbet.es/es/live/animation/5610082"
    #

    # Realizamos la petición a la web
    req = requests.get(URL)

    # Comprobamos que la petición nos devuelve un Status Code = 200
    status_code = req.status_code
    if status_code == 200:

        # Pasamos el contenido HTML de la web a un objeto BeautifulSoup()
        html = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

        resultadoytiempo=html.find('td',{'class':'event-description'})

        print ("%s" %resultadoytiempo.getText())


        # Obtenemos todos los divs donde están las entradas sobre precio y resultado 
        entradas = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'nowrap simple-price'})

        # Recorremos todas las entradas para extraer el resultado y su cuota
        for i, entrada in enumerate(entradas):
            # Con el método "getText()" no nos devuelve el HTML
            equipo1 = entrada.find('span', {'class': 'left-simple'}).getText()
            cuota1= entrada.find('span', {'class': 'right-simple'}).getText()

            # Imprimo el equipo/resultado y cuota
            print ("%d - %s  |  %s "  % (i + 1, equipo1, cuota1) )

    else:
        print ("Status Code %d" % status_code)


else:
    print ("Falta argumento: url de la página mbet a analizar");
```

Thanks  :)

I edit the

print ("%s" %resultadoytiempo).getText()

to

print ("%s" %resultadoytiempo.getText())

but nothing changes

Comment: ("%s" %resultadoytiempo) is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

This causes getNext to be called on retrun value of print function

```
print ("%s" %resultadoytiempo).getText()
```

Use the following

```
if resultadoytiempo is not None:
    print ("%s" %resultadoytiempo.getText())
```

Comment: Nothing, same error: `  File "extrae2.py", line 27, in <module>
    print ("%s" %resultadoytiempo.getText())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'   `

Comment: that means `resultadoytiempo` is None , you may check that first . Check the updated answer

Answer (score -1):

`print` doesn't return anything, so you can't call `getText` on what it returns.

Comment: so, what can I do?